# assemblercode generated by gcc results in fatal error when assembled by ARM-assembler

Tags: gcc, armasm

I found out that the ARM-compiler `armcc V5.05` does not compile `uint64_t` correctly into assembly code. It uses only one register instead of two so the result is truncated to 32 bits (though the compiler is not complaining). 
As a workaround I used the gcc compiler, put the generated assembler code into a separate asm file and ran the ARM assembler. The target could not be created due to the error:

> This register combination results in UNPREDICTABLE behaviour

which is really fatal,  I suppose. After the C- "return" statement at the end of a function gcc inserts an offending `SUB SP,R11,#0` or `ADD SP,R11,#0` command before the ASM-return command `BX LR`. This is true with or without `uint64_t`. 
Can I rely on gcc or is it a bug in armcc/armasm?

Comment: Hello trylimits,
thanks for formatting ! I just wanted to make things clearer when I saw that the source code wasn't complete. After completion there are no more `SUB SP` or `ADD SP` so gcc is reliable of course. But it doesn't compile uint64_t correctly, the same way armcc does.